# Avoiding Content-Length in HEAD response

Tags: http, http-headers

The Content-Length response header is often expensive to generate for a just HEAD request (e.g. when dealing with dynamically generated resources), but may be essentially "free" after doing the work needed to generate a GET response body.

When it is reasonable to provide a Content-Length (instead of a chunked response) when responding to a GET request, yet unreasonable or slow to calculate the Content-Length for the corresponding HEAD request, is it permissible for the HEAD response to:

- Omit the Content-Length header altogether?
- Respond with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` even though GET response would have a `Content-Length`?

The [relevant W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) indicates that a HEAD request "SHOULD" (*not* "MUST") respond with identical headers; is the cleanliness and, admittedly often minor, total transfer size savings of using Content-Length in the GET response worth violating the aforementioned "SHOULD" in the case of HEAD, or is the only reasonable choice to have both responses send a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header?

Comment: W3C specs generally don't consider conputational or other resource limitations. The real world is not so forgiving. IMO, it's ok to break spec in order to provide a better experience for the end-user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from @julian-reschke, [rfc-7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) indicates that:

> The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, except that the payload header fields (Section 3.3) MAY be omitted.

Per [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3) of that same document, the payload header fields consist of:

- Content-Length
- Content-Range
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding